# How to get the cart items from magento soap api

Tags: api, soap, soap-client, cart, magento-1.9

I have created a soap client Api for magento, my requirement is to get the current user shopping cart added items. How can i get this?

```
        $host = "localhost/magformers_theme/index.php"; //our online shop url
        $client = new SoapClient("http://".$host."/api/soap/?wsdl"); //soap handle
        $apiuser= "user"; //webservice user login
        $apikey = "magentouser"; //webservice user pass
        $action = "sales_order.list"; //an action to call later (loading Sales Order List)
        try { 

          $sess_id= $client->login($apiuser, $apikey); //we do login


        //print_r($client->call($sess_id, $action));
        $result = $client->call($sess_id, 'catalog_product.list');
        var_dump ($result);
        }
        catch (Exception $e) { //while an error has occured
            echo "==> Error: ".$e->getMessage(); //we print this
               exit();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is for .net api v1

String mlogin = mservice.login("username", "password");

var info = mservice.shoppingCartInfo(mlogin, 9, null);

here 9 is quote id and mservice is the login authentication.